# Filtering in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have rather a simple question but couldn't find an answer for it.
I have an array as following:

```
sample = np.random.uniform(0,1,1000)
```

and I would like to filter values between 0.1 and 0.13 plus values above 0.9.

```
filter1 = sample[((sample > 0.1) & (sample <0.13)) & (sample > 0.9)]
```

However, the code gives an empty array. I don't know if I am doing a mistake regarding parenthesis. I appreciate it if you point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

You are currently filtering for numbers that are above 0.1, below 0.13, and above 0.9; a number must meet all three criteria to meet your requirements.

To fix this, change your second ampersand to a pipe, such that the filtering reads "(numbers above 0.1 and below 0.13), or above 0.9":

```py
filter1 = sample[((sample > 0.1) & (sample <0.13)) | (sample > 0.9)]
```